# Adding a Cocoapod to a Cocoapod

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am creating my own custom library and I want to implement a QR Code Reader in it.

My plan was to add a QR Code reader cocoapod to my library, but I am struggling to do that.

Any tips?

Comment: why need to add extra dependencies? you can easily create QR code scanner using AVFoundation no need to add in a cocoa pod.

Answer (score 4):

You can certainly do this. You add the other pod as a dependency of your own pod in the `podspec` file.

e.g. `spec.dependency 'MyQRCodeReaderPod', '~> 1.0'`

Here's the official guide:
https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency

Comment: That makes sense. Now that its in my podspec file though, do I have to import it? I cannot seem to utilize it in my code.

Comment: You'll probably need to do a `pod install` to make sure all dependencies of your pod are installed.

Comment: @CalebRudnicki you will need to import the other pod into your current pod where you want to use it